# fprintf with mixture of strings and numbers

Tags: matlab, printf

I would like to produce a text file which includes a mixture of strings and numbers. The example is as follows:

```
clear all
fakeData = @(location) struct('Location',location,'AirT',rand(320,1),'SolRad',rand(320,1),'Rain',rand(320,1));
  s(1) = fakeData('England');
  s(2) = fakeData('Wales');
  s(3) = fakeData('Scotland');
  s(4) = fakeData('Ireland');
FieldName = {s.Location};
R = corrcoef([s.AirT],'rows','pairwise');
R_Values = [FieldName(nchoosek(1:size(R,1),2)) num2cell(nonzeros(tril(R,-1)))];
MeanCorr = mean(cell2mat(R_Values(:,3)));
Headings = {'L1','L2','Correlation'};
R_Values1 = [Headings;R_Values];
R_Values1 = [R_Values1; {'','Mean',MeanCorr}];
```

In order to print R_Values I would simply type:

```
 for i=11:length(R_Values);
fprintf(1,'%12s\t%12s\t%9.6f\n',R_Values{i,1},R_Values{i,2},R_Values{i,3})
  end
```

However, when trying to do this for R_Values1 I fail, Im not sure how to allow for the different format in the first and last line of R_Values1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the heading row has a different format than the data rows, I see two options.

1. print the heading row with a separate `fprintf` statement or;
2. use `xlswrite` to write the cell array `R_Values1` to a file. According to the MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) 'xlswrite' will create a CSV file if Excel is not available otherwise it will create Excel file which might not work for you.

Maybe others might have different suggestions for handling the header row.

Comment: after some trial and error I have found that by replacing the line with fprintf to:
    fprintf(1,'%-12s\t%-12s\t%-12s\n',R_Values1{i,1},R_Values1{i,2},R_Values1{i,3})
 The code does write in the correct format but its not entirely the same as in R_Values1

Comment: Just tried printing the heading row with a separate fprintf statement and it worked perfectly. thanks.

Comment: @user1155751 glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB: to write strings and numbers in the same file, you need to

1) convert number to formatted string using sprintf

2) concat all strings

3) use fprintf to write to file

Example: you want to write Nx1 array Strings and Nx1 array Numbers to Fileout.txt

```
    % define output file and clean old versions:
    fileout='Fileout.txt'
    system(['rm -f ' fileout]);

    % open output file in the 'a'ppend mode
    fid=fopen(fileout,'a');

    % loop over all lines of both arrays:
    for i= 1:size(Numbers,1)
        s = sprintf('%10.3f',Numbers(i));
        fprintf(fid,'%s\n',[Strings(i,:) s]);
    end
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without a loop?